# Attempt to read from field in AndroidDevMetrics on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, metrics, code-metrics

I am trying to implement frogermcs/AndroidDevMetrics library in my project

This is the link: https://github.com/frogermcs/AndroidDevMetrics

I followed these steps to integrate AndroidDevMetrics into my project.

Added these in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics:androiddevmetrics-plugin:0.7'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics
```

Then in your Activity class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Use it only in debug builds
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        AndroidDevMetrics.initWith(this);
    }
}
```

For this when i run my project and came to that activity where init code is. The app crash with the statement:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.project/com.mycompany.project.activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics.internal.metrics.ActivityLifecycleMetrics$ActivityLifecycleMetric.state' on a null object reference
> ```

And here are some other logs from middle of logs

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics.internal.metrics.ActivityLifecycleMetrics$ActivityLifecycleMetric.state' on a null object reference at com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics.internal.metrics.ActivityLifecycleMetrics.logPostOnStart(ActivityLifecycleMetrics.java:88) at com.frogermcs.androiddevmetrics.internal.metrics.ActivityLaunchMetrics.onActivityStarted(ActivityLaunchMetrics.java:43)

Please guide me where i am wrong. or how to solve this issue to getting AndroidDevMetrics into work. Thanks

Gradle Version: 5.0

Android Plugin Version: 3.3.0

AndroidDevMetrics Library Version: 0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should be in your application class

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     //Use it only in debug builds
     if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
         AndroidDevMetrics.initWith(this);
     }
  }
 }
```

And in you Manifest please add below lines of code

```
<application
        android:name=".ExampleApplication "
-----        
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks i had already done that. But your answer is correct. Thanks